# How to get only objects from list where property x is not null in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of projects

```
List<Project> projects = ProjectRepository.GetProjects(user);
```

This returns me the users projects. Each projects can have a property called `ProjectServerUrl`. I want to get only those projects from List where the object property ProjectServerUrl is not null. I have tried the following line of code, but it returns me always all items:

```
List<Project> listP = projects.Where(x => (x.ProjectServerUrl != null || x.ProjectServerUrl != "")).ToList();
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The OR will make sure the null ones get through..

Comment: Is `ProjectServerUrl` a string?

Comment: I am developing now for hours and worked also some time on this. Seems that i am blind now and should have a break. Thank you!

Comment: Yes ProjectServerUrl is a string.

Comment: STORM, I can sympathize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var listP = projects
    .Where(x => (x.ProjectServerUrl != null && x.ProjectServerUrl != ""))
    .ToList();
```

I think your `||` needs to be a `&&`.

You can simplify this:

```
var listP = projects
    .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are asking to get all projects where ProjectServerUrl is null OR is empty. You have to use AND

```
List<Project> listP = projects.Where(x => (x.ProjectServerUrl != null && x.ProjectServerUrl != "")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**

In your Where clause, you are using the OR operator which is why you are still receiving objects in your list even though they are null or blank...

For example, `ProjectServerUrl` doesn't equal null but that doesn't mean it's *empty* or just white space.  Basically the OR operator needs to be changed to &&

So change this:

```
List<Project> listP = projects.Where(x => (x.ProjectServerUrl != null || x.ProjectServerUrl != "")).ToList();
```

To:

```
List<Project> listP = projects.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ProjectServerUrl)).ToList();
```

This way you're protected against null, empty or white space values.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mean `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.ProjectServerUrl)` and `string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProjectServerUrl)`? You're using them like a property which I don't think is right. Also, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` should handle cases for "empty", so you shouldn't need both.

Comment: @DangerZone edited! you're correct, I think after .Net Framework 4.0 IsNullOrWhiteSpace handles all, so thank you